# Error in ASP.NET (Server Error in '/' Application.)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-authentication

for about month I'm trying to solve this problem which is driving me mad, so i said to myself let me post it on this site so may some one could help me.

let's get to the point

my program is asp.net connected to SQL Server 2008, once i try to run the program using the visual studio 2008 it just give this error as shown below

```
Login failed for user 'sa'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849015
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2394
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +144
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +342
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +221
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +433
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState& originalState) +31
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +112
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +287
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +92
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1297
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +22
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +18
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

Comment: @john @abat - Yes...OP may have some comprehension issues with that error message...however this kind of sarcastic crap doesn't belong on SO. Either give a straight answer or vote to close/flag.

Comment: @Kev: that wasn't sarcasm. It was helpful. Someone who can't understand "login failed" for a month needs to reconsider the reasons for that.

Comment: Ladies, let's all calm down...

Answer (score 4):

the error is in the text... you cannot connect to the sql server with the user SA.

Check :

- if the password in the connexion string is OK
- if sql allow sql logins and not only windows logins
- if you can connect to Sql server from visual studio with the exact string you pass

A out-of-subject comment : Windows auth is often preferable ...

Answer (score 2):

You have a misconfigured connection string. You are apparently attempting to login to your SQL server with the `sa` account (not recommended). You should enable a different user with the proper permissions in your SQL server, then use this user to perform connections with. Once you solve your login credentials issue in your connection string you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to do with your `ConnectionString`.  You are using a user ID of `sa`.  This means that your using SQL Authentication.  You need to supply the password for the `sa` user as well.

If you have supplied the password and it's correct, you might want to check to see if `sa` is `enabled` in SQL Server.